# UISearchBar searches history

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I'd like to show user history of his previous searches in UISearchBar so he can choose from the list instead of retyping.

Is there any built-in control in xcode for this, or i have to implement it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in control that does what you want. Searchbar doesn't even know what was previous search terms. You have to save it somewhere (Array or dictionary) for all or last 10 search terms and display in whichever you want.

Comment: Do I have to create a table in core data and save all the strings that I want?

Comment: As far as I know, YES, if you want save them all permanently.

Comment: You can also create Settings using UserDefaults and store an array of strings there with the help of singleton pattern.